# Why there is a difference from amplitude calculated from PSD and the real one?

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, python, power-spectral-density, random-process

I make a script in python to extract amplitude from power spectral density.
I try to verif it but I have a difference between the real amplitude and the amplitude extracted from PSD.

To calculate the PSD, I use the welch method.
Where amplitude H = square root (8*S(f)*df)
df = the frequency step

Can anyone give me some help to find the error.
the red line is real amplitude, the blue line is calculated.
From the figure, the error was proportional to the amplitude.
[image]

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
N=5 # number of component waves
height=[0.91,1.83,2.17,4.18,2.38]
period=[3.76,5.04,6.63,8.69,13.03]
phase = [np.pi/2,np.pi,0,0,np.pi]
freq=[]
for T in period:
f=1/T
freq.append(f)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
N=5 # number of component waves
height=[0.91,1.83,2.17,4.18,2.38]
period=[3.76,5.04,6.63,8.69,13.03]
phase = [np.pi/2,np.pi,0,0,np.pi]
freq=[]
for T in period:
f=1/T
freq.append(f)`

## welch method

tpas = t[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iJ20.png)-t[0]
fs = 1/tpas

## f_PSD frequency from welch method

f_PSD, PSD = signal.welch(nus, fs, nperseg=ninterval)
f_taked = f_PSD
N_taked = f_taked.size
fs1=0
for i in range(N_taked-1):
fs1max=f_taked[i+1]-f_taked[i]
if fs1max>fs1:
fs1=fs1max
H_taked = np.sqrt(8*PSD*fs1)
plt.plot(f_taked,H_taked)
plt.plot(freq, height,'r')
plt.xlim(0,0.4)
plt.show()

Comment: Hi Tarek- Welcome to DSP.SE! Can you just modify your original question? This is basically the same thing, isn't it? https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/82544/how-to-take-amplitude-and-frequency-from-the-power-spectral-density

Comment: Yes, the first question "How to take the amplitude from PSD ?" is solved in this question.
But the probleme is that the amplitudes taked from PSD were different from the original one (which generate the time series)